# Extracting data from a Solar Inverter, UDP Broadcast?

Tags: android, python, udp, broadcast

First post here, so please let me know if any extra detail would be useful.

I am trying to extract data from a WiFi enabled Solar PV inverter (e.g. Power generation vs time,  Energy generated today, battery charge level etc). 
There is an android app in the playstore called kstarmg which does some of this already but only works when connected to the local network, so not accessible via the Internet. I want to write something to run on a local machine (raspberry pi) that logs data from the inverter and updates a web page. My first thought is to use python.

I have managed to decompile the android app apk and so far as I can see it uses a UDP broadcast to communicate with the inverter. So far as I can see it sends some text "WIFIKIT-214028-READ" on port 48899. I have managed to see this text by listening with nc on the raspberry pi. I am struggling to work out how to read responses from the inverter. Can anyone point me towards how I can determine how to read data from the inverter?

I tried the following in python but got nothing back:

```
import socket
import struct

import sys
message = 'WIFIKIT-214028-READ'
multicast_group = ('224.3.29.71', 48899)
# Create the datagram socket                                                                                     sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
# Set a timeout so the socket does not block indefinitely when trying to receive data.
sock.settimeout(20)
# Set the time-to-live for messages to 1 so they do not go past the local network segment.                       ttl = struct.pack('b', 1)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, ttl)                                                 
try:
    # Send data to the multicast group
    print >>sys.stderr, 'sending "%s"' % message                                                                     sent = sock.sendto(message, multicast_group)
    # Look for responses from all recipients                                                                         while True:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting to receive'
        try:
            data, server = sock.recvfrom(16)
        except socket.timeout:
            print >>sys.stderr, 'timed out, no more responses'                                                               break
        else:
            print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s" from %s' % (data, server)
finally:                                                                                                             print >>sys.stderr, 'closing socket'
    sock.close()
```

Some of the lines from the android apk that seem relevant are:

```
package com.kstar.common;

import android.util.Log;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class UdpBroadcast {
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 100;
    private static final String TAG = "UdpBroadcast";
    private InetAddress inetAddress;
    private DatagramPacket packetToSend;
    private int port;
    private ReceiveData receiveData;
    private DatagramSocket socket;

    /* renamed from: com.kstar.common.UdpBroadcast.1 */
    class C00521 extends Thread {
        C00521() {
        }

        public void run() {
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(new byte[UdpBroadcast.BUFFER_SIZE], UdpBroadcast.BUFFER_SIZE);
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (System.currentTimeMillis() - time < 300) {
                try {
                    UdpBroadcast.this.socket.receive(packet);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
            try {
                Log.i(UdpBroadcast.TAG, "--UdpBroadcast Send:  ------------>" + new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").format(new Date()));
                UdpBroadcast.this.socket.setSoTimeout(1000);
                UdpBroadcast.this.socket.send(UdpBroadcast.this.packetToSend);
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            UdpBroadcast.this.receiveData = new ReceiveData(null);
            Log.i(UdpBroadcast.TAG, "--UdpBroadcast receiveData:  ------------>" + new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").format(new Date()));
            UdpBroadcast.this.receiveData.start();
        }
    }

    private class ReceiveData implements Runnable {
        private List<DatagramPacket> packets;
        private boolean stop;
        private Thread thread;

        private ReceiveData() {
            this.thread = new Thread(this);
            this.packets = new ArrayList();
        }

        public void run() {
            this.stop = false;
            while (!this.stop) {
                try {
                    DatagramPacket packetToReceive = new DatagramPacket(new byte[UdpBroadcast.BUFFER_SIZE], UdpBroadcast.BUFFER_SIZE);
                    UdpBroadcast.this.socket.receive(packetToReceive);
                    this.packets.add(packetToReceive);
                } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (!this.stop) {
                UdpBroadcast.this.onReceived(this.packets);
            }
            this.stop = true;
        }

        void start() {
            this.thread.start();
        }

        void stop() {
            this.stop = true;
        }

        boolean isStoped() {
            return this.stop;
        }
    }

    public abstract void onReceived(List<DatagramPacket> list);

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public UdpBroadcast() {
        this.port = Constant.UDP_PORT;
        this.socket = null;
        try {
            this.inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("255.255.255.255");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void open() {
        try {
            if (this.socket == null) {
                this.socket = new DatagramSocket(this.port);
                this.socket.setBroadcast(true);
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        stopReceive();
        if (this.socket != null) {
            this.socket.close();
            this.socket = null;
        }
    }

    public void send(String text) {
        if (this.socket != null && text != null) {
            text = text.trim();
            this.packetToSend = new DatagramPacket(text.getBytes(), text.getBytes().length, this.inetAddress, this.port);
            try {
                this.socket.setSoTimeout(500);
                stopReceive();
                new C00521().start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopReceive() {
        if (this.receiveData != null && !this.receiveData.isStoped()) {
            this.receiveData.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

I am struggling to work out what to do next to work out what is going on so any advice would be very gratefully received

Thanks

Graham

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with PHP in order to change the timers on the inverter, maybe this will help.
First I installed a packet sniffer (I used HttpCanary) to find the command to change timers.
For example "AA55B07F02390B0701040E00173BFFF1FF7F064E" would set the 1st timer to 14:00.
And I used the following function, most of it picked from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007897/udp-socket-programming-in-php)

```
function send_socket(){
$server = '137.134.128.220';
$port = 13435;
$return="Not OK";
if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0))){
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
    $return="Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg";
    return $return;
}
$return="Socket created";

$output = hex2bin("AA55B07F02390B0701040E00173BFFF1FF7F064E");//start at 2


//Send the message to the server
if( ! socket_sendto($sock, $output , strlen($output) , 0 , $server , $port)){
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
    $return="Could not send data: [$errorcode] $errormsg";
    return $return;
}

//Now receive reply from server and print it
if(socket_recv ( $sock , $reply , 2045 , MSG_WAITALL ) === FALSE){
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
    $return="Could not receive data: [$errorcode] $errormsg";
    return $return;
}

$return=bin2hex($reply);
echo "Reply: $return";
if ($return=="aa557fb002b9010602f0"){
    $return="Success";
}
return $return;
}
```